# How to add day to the date time chart label in the format "dd:HH:mm:ss" using c#

Tags: c#

I am developing chart using windows forms application. I am implementing line chart of DateTime type. I need to add real time data to chart for every 1 second upto 1 week. Always I have to show 10 minutes data(like 0-10 min,10-20 min,20-30 min...). So I fixed the minimum and maximum values of chart for every 10 minutes in the format "HH:mm:ss".While I am continuously adding data to chart, after '23:59:59' it is displaying '00:00:00'. So User do not know which day data currently updating. So is there any provision to add 'day' field to the datetime chart? Please guide in this regard.

```
series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;                        
series1.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
series1.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chart1.Series.Add(series1);

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss";

DateTime minValue = DateTime.Now;

DateTime  maxValue = minValue.AddSeconds(600);

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minValue.ToOADate();
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxValue.ToOADate();
```

Comment: `dt.ToString("dd:HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: Have you tried just changing the format to include the day, per your title?

Comment: @Tim: I tried "dd:HH:mm:ss". But it is displaying today date 11. That means "11:13:42:40"

Comment: See [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - that's expected.  If you want the day of the week, you need `ddd` or `dddd`.

Comment: @Charles: Chart has to display the days based on tool running days. For example if app runs for 2 days continuously, it has to show "02:14:47:55"

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri that information isn't contained in a `DateTime`, which (as its name suggests) contains the actual date.